# Verify and decode Cognito JWT in nodejs with smallest code footprint

Tags: node.js, jwt, amazon-cognito, jwk

I have an application that runs as AWS Lambda function using Cognito authentication. It all works fine but now I am attempting to optimise the bundle size to reduce cold start times.

The process of verifying and decoding the JWT involves:

- Fetch JWK from internal AWS endpoint
- Call jwkToPem from jwk-to-pem module
- Verify and decode JWT using jsonwebtoken module

When I look at the `node_modules` in my archive, the largest packages are all related to the steps above:

```
elliptic 140kb
bn.js 108kb
jsonwebtoken 84kb
hash.js 80kb
asn1.js 72kb
hmac-drbg 36kb
jwk-to-pem 32kb

Total ~550kb
```

This is over half of `node_modules` size and my application code is just 164kb un-minified, so as you can see the JWT decode has a substantial impact on overall bundle size.

Am wondering if there is a lighter weight alternative...

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the "Fetch JWK from internal AWS endpoint" step is fetching from a JSON Web Key Set, the [`jose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) version 3.x module can do everything for you.

The disk size is bigger, but that's because it's a universal module and bundles runtime also for the web, in both esm and cjs flavours, but don't fret - in your runtime it requires only the node runtime files and has 0 dependencies. And you can use rollup to tree-shake all of the weight you're not using (other submodules and runtime files).

```
import jwtVerify from 'jose/jwt/verify'
import createRemoteJWKSet from 'jose/jwks/remote'

const JWKS = createRemoteJWKSet(new URL('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs'))

const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jwtVerify(token, JWKS, {
  issuer: 'urn:example:issuer',
  audience: 'urn:example:audience'
})
```

Comment: Sounds good thanks, but I tried running rollup on my entry file and it just output the file more or less unchanged, it didn't bundle or tree shake anything. Is there a one-liner that will make rollup do what you suggest or do I need to configure one or more plugins? A link to the basic steps would be really useful. Tx again

Comment: esbuild can do it too. I use it in jose's test suite to make a tree shaken browser bundle. https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/08b16d318325f928068b417c0282b1a54b7f0708/package.json#L345

Comment: Thanks esbuild looks promising!

Comment: My entire lambda package archive is now 21kb... amazing! Still working through making sure everything is working but looks like it is... thank you.